# TypeError: Cannot read property 'comment' of undefined in React

Tags: reactjs

<DishDetail dish={this.state.dishes.filter((dish) => dish.id === this.state.selectedDish)[0]} />
This is passing the dish details from the MainComponent to my DishDetailComponent.

{this.renderDish(this.props.dish)}
This is receiving the dish details and properly rendering the dish title and description. But,
{this.renderComments(this.props.dish.comments)} whenever this is executed, I am getting that error.

P.S: I have checked using console.log(this.props.dish) to confirm that the dish object is correctly getting passed.

Comment: You should post some code (the renderComments methods by the looks of things). But the error is about a property called "comment", and there are no properties called "comment" in your post, just one called "comments" (plural). So you might be looking at the wrong line.

Answer (score 0):

What I think is happening with your code is that in certain moment, when your component is rendering, this.props.dish is undefined. You can avoid that error using a check for this so you do not call a property of an object that is not defined. You can do this:

```
this.props?.dish?.comments
```

Comment: Please provide some explanation why do you think your proposed solution might help the OP. If this is just an educated guess then make this suggestion as a comment , not as answer.